# Error not clarifying what is keeping my program from parsing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I am running an error check, since my edit post function is not working, and this is the message I am getting

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column 'trewfh' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\Forum\editpost.php:55 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\Forum\editpost.php(55): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE hw7_foru...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\Forum\editpost.php(39): editpost(72, 'trewfh') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Final\Forum\editpost.php on line 55

What a confusing error message! It is echoing out exactly what I want it to (the id =72 and the random string =trewfh) however nothing occurs in terms of updating my post. The $connectDB variable comes from including my connection file and universally works everywhere with no issues. I was hoping someone could see what I am not. Thanks for your time and assistance!!!

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);

    include 'header.php';
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    //GATHER MY POST THAT MATCHES THE POST THE USER CLICKS TO EDIT AND DISPLAY TO THEM!
    $sql = "SELECT forumpost_ID, forumpost_Text
            FROM hw7_forumpost
            WHERE forumpost_ID =" . mysqli_real_escape_string($connectDB, $_GET['eid']);
    $result = mysqli_query($connectDB,$sql);
    if(!$result){ echo 'Something went wrong, please try again later.'; }
    else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo'<form action="" method="post">';
            echo'<div>';
            echo'<textarea name="contents" rows="15" cols="50">'.$row[1].'</textarea>';
            echo'</div><div>';
            echo'<input type="submit" value="Add Post">';
            echo'</div>';
        }echo '</form>';
    }       
    if(isset($_POST['contents'])){
        $contents = trim($_POST['contents']);
        editpost($_GET['eid'], $contents);
        echo ('Your post has been updated!');
        header('index.php');
        die();
    }
    include 'footer.php';
    /********************************************
    edit function
    **********************************************/
    function editpost($id, $contents){
        global $connectDB;
        $id = (int)$id;
        $contents = mysqli_real_escape_string($connectDB, $contents);
        $sql = "UPDATE hw7_forumpost SET forumpost_Text=".$contents." WHERE forumpost_ID= ".$id;
        $result = mysqli_query($connectDB, $sql);
   }
?>
```

My update should be saying hey database Update hw7_forumpost SET forumpost_Text = 'Trewfh' WHERE forumpost_ID = The correct id it's Getting via $_GET. Its reading everything fine like I said when it's echoing. Something random is happening along the way through

Comment: Which of your SQL statements produces the error?  What's the actual runtime value of the SQL statement you're trying to execute?  (You should really be using query parameters instead of string concatenation.  This would not only allow you to actually control the syntax of your query but also help protect against SQL injection.)

Comment: It's happening when I grab the $_POST from the form that updates the post (in this case random letters Trew to Trewfh) and run it through my function. The Trewfh should be the $content updating in the column of forumpost_Text, but it errors out.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to wrap a string in quotes in your SQL code.  Your code is treating the value in `$contents` as a column identifier instead of a string literal.  Using query parameters would make the problem moot, by the way.

Comment: When the error reads my function it is showing the id as an int like i want it to and the random text as a string, as it should!

Comment: Could you clarify on that a bit? I'm not sure where you found that mistake!

Comment: *"My update should be saying..."* - But what ***is*** it saying?  Stop shouting at the code and start actually debugging.  What is the *actual runtime value* of `$sql`, the *actual SQL code* that you're trying to execute?  Examine it and you'll see that it's: `UPDATE hw7_forumpost SET forumpost_Text=trewfh WHERE forumpost_ID= 72`  Just as the error states, `trewfh` is not a known column in that table.  String literals need to be wrapped in quotes.  (Or, again, use query parameters and the database engine will take care of the string types for you.)

Comment: You saved my butt, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE hw7_forumpost SET `forumpost_Text` = -->'<--".$contents."-->'<-- WHERE `forumpost_ID` = ".$id;
```

It was a simple case of forgetting to place a ' ' in between calling contents as David has pointed out. Thank you David!!!!